# Air preasure vs temperature

Tags: pressure, temperature

Suppose you have a container of 1 liter of air at sea level with an initial pressure of 1 atmosphere.
How high could the pressure get by only raising the temperature.

Is there a point (providing the vessel is indestructible) at which only raising the temperature will no longer raise the pressure?

Can this pressure be a useful tool for temperature indication?

Comment: No, but when the *air* gets hot enough it turns into a plasma and at that point it isn't air anymore.

Comment: This is a very nice question in terms of physics especially when Ideal Gas Law can no longer be valid at such high temperatures and Plasma Physics need to step in. I am sure there are some physicists here whose expertise will allow them to answer this question in a more systematic way.

Comment: The pressure will cease to rise only when the energy content in the vessel has reached such tremendously high values that gravity becomes important. At that point the pressure at the boundary will drop, but the central pressure will continue to increase. At high enough temperatures the system will collapse to a black hole.

Comment: So as long as the vessel can take the heat the pressure will rise? Will it rise linearly?(1 atmosphere  at 0 Celsius, x atmosphere at 100 c, 2x  at 200 c and so on) What vessel material will stand the highest temp without being compromised?

Comment: I am trying to find out the pressure properties of air in order to find if I can use the pressure of expanding air as a temperature gauge, can´t get more physics than that mister moderator.